# Ruby - determine if a number is a prime

Tags: ruby

I'm running through the problems on [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net) to teach myself Ruby programming.  *I know there is a built-in function to do this*, but I'm avoiding the built-in functions to help me learn.

So I have to write a method to determine if a number is a prime.  The first method works, but the second doesn't.  Can anyone explain why?

```
 def is_prime n
  for d in 2..(n - 1)
   if (n % d) == 0
    return false
   end
  end

  true
 end

 def is_prime2 n
  foundDivider = false
   for d in 2..(n - 1)
    foundDivider = ((n % d) == 0) or foundDivider
   end
  not foundDivider
 end
```

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question… but why are you checking all those numbers after you've found it's not a prime? You've *already* got a definitive answer to your question.

Comment: Yeah I realized that - but I was doing it that way to make sure I know how boolean operators work in Ruby

Comment: More efficient algorithm can be develop with following approach: don't iterate over even numbers (not just skip them) and cut the loop to 5-10% of original size. Details are here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26792960/why-doesnt-my-ruby-coding-for-finding-prime-numbers-work/32806718#32806718

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's because `=` is of higher precedence than `or`. See [Ruby's operator precedence table](http://phrogz.net/ProgrammingRuby/language.html#table_18.4) below (highest to lowest precedence):

```
[ ] [ ]=
**
! ~ + -
* / %
+ -
>> <<
&
^ |
<= < > >=
<=> == === != =~ !~
&&
||
.. ...
? :
= %= { /= -= += |= &= >>= <<= *= &&= ||= **=
defined?
not
or and
if unless while until
begin/end
```

The problematic line is being parsed as...

```
(foundDivider = ((n % d) == 0)) or foundDivider
```

...which is certainly not what you mean.  There are two possible solutions:

Force the precedence to be what you really mean...

```
foundDivider = (((n % d) == 0) or foundDivider)
```

...or use the `||` operator instead, which has higher precedence than `=`:

```
foundDivider = ((n % d) == 0) || foundDivider
```

Comment: This is why I love StackOverflow.  Thanks a million

Comment: Nice. I found the question, and the answer useful! I too am running through Project Euler to learn Ruby. One performance improvement suggestion I have is to change the range from **2..(n-1)** to **2..(Math.sqrt(n))**; reduces the number of iterations significantly.

Comment: writing foundDivider ||= ((n%d) == 0) will be more nice.

Answer (score 13):

Ruby comes with predefined classes such as Prime. All you have to do is to require that class into your project.

```
require 'prime'
```

Than, you can use some of the Prime methods such as **first** to get first x prime elements:

```
Prime.first(5) # Ret => [2, 3, 5, 6, 11]
```

Or you could do something like this:

```
Prime.each(100) do |prime|
  p prime # Ret => [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, ..., 97]
end
```

I hope you find this useful.

Answer (score 10):

```
def prime(n)
  return false if n < 2

  (2..n/2).none?{|i| n % i == 0}
end
```

A prime number is any number that has no positive divisors other than itself and 1.

Answer (score 5):

Find prime numbers from loop:

```
def get_prime_no_upto(number)
  pre = [1]
  start = 2
  primes = (start..number).to_a
  (start..number).each do |no|
    (start..no).each do |num|
      if ( no % num  == 0) && num != no
        primes.delete(no)
        break
      end
    end
  end
  pre + primes
end
```

and use it as below:

```
puts get_prime_no_upto(100)
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

```
def prime? n
  (2..Math.sqrt(n)).none? {|f| n % f == 0}
end
```

The range of factors should start at 2 and end at the square root of n because every number is divisible by one and no number is divisible by two numbers greater than its square root.

Explanation: A non-prime number is the product of two numbers.

```
n = f1 * f2
```

`n` is always divisible by its square root so both `f1` and `f2` cannot be greater than the square root of n, otherwise `f1 * f2` would be greater than `n`. Therefore, at least one factor is less than or at most equal to `Math.sqrt(n)`. In the case of finding prime numbers its only necessary to find one factor so we should loop from `2` to the square root of `n`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is code that will prompt you to enter a number for prime check:

```
puts "welcome to prime number check"
puts "enter number for check: "
  n = gets
  n = n.to_i

def prime(n)
  puts "That's not an integer." unless n.is_a? Integer
  is_prime = true
  for i in 2..n-1
    if n % i == 0
      is_prime = false
    end
  end
  if is_prime
    puts "#{n} is prime!"
  else
    puts "#{n} is not prime."
  end
end

prime(n)
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the answer by Darmouse but including edge cases

```
def prime? (n)
    if n <= 1
        false
    elsif n == 2
        true
    else 
        (2..n/2).none? { |i| n % i == 0}
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

FYI - re: DarkMouses prime method above - I found it really helpful, but there are a few errors (I think!) that need explaining:

It should be parentheses rather than square brackets... Otherwise you get a TypeError

```
Range can't be coerced into Fixnum (TypeError)
```

Secondly, that first colon before 'false' would cause an error too. It's incorrect syntax, as far as I know. Get rid of it.

Lastly, I think you got it the wrong way round?? If you correct the errors I mentioned, it returns true if it ISN'T a prime, and false if it IS.

You can drop the ternary operator altogether I think, and just do:

```
def prime?(n)
  (2..n/2).none?{|i| n % i == 0} 
end
```

Obviously it doesn't cover the edge cases (0,1,2), but let's not split hairs.

...For those who enjoy hairsplitting, here is my full solution to this problem:

```
    def prime?(n)
      return false if n < 2
      (2..Math.sqrt(n)).none? {|num| length % num == 0}
    end
```

Hope I didn't miss anything :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a little bit off topic according to the details, but correct for the title : using bash integration in ruby you could do :

```
def is_prime n
    `factor #{n}`.split.count < 3
end
```

bash `factor` function returns a number plus all of his factors, so if the number is prime, there will be two words count.

This is usefull for **code golf** only.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked:

```
def prime?(n)
  return false if n < 2 
  return true if n == 3 || n == 2 
    if (2...n-1).any?{|i| n % i == 0}
      false
    else
      true
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def prime?(n)
  if n <= 1
  return false

  else (2..n-1).to_a.all? do |integer|
   n % integer != 0

   end
  end
end
```

From my prime? lab. Started with eliminating all integers less than or equal to 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
def prime(n)
    pn = [2]
    if n < 2
       return false

   else

     (2..n).each do |i|
       not_prime = false

        (2..Math.sqrt(i).ceil).each do |j|
           not_prime = true if i % j == 0    
        end
       pn.push(i) unless not_prime
    end

 end

return pn

end
```

p prime(30) gives

`[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29]`

Answer (score 0):

It will return true if the number is prime.

```
def prime_number(number)
  
    (2..(number-1)).each do |value|   
        
        if (number % value) == 0
            return false
        end
        
        return true
    end    
end

puts prime_number(4)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Object
    private
def prime? num
    if (2..3).include? num
        return true
    else
        !num.even? and num % 3 != 0 and num > 1
    end
 end
end
```

prime? 1
prime? 2
prime? 9
prime? 17

Answer (score -2):

** FOR A SIMPLE SHORTED METHOD**
**FIRST INSTALL PRIME GEM**

```
require 'prime'
`p prime.first(20)`
```

*Now save that file as your desired name, this will generate the first 20 prime numbers Automatically!! :-)*