# Trying to figure out if user input is prime or not with ruby

Tags: ruby

I am new to Ruby and just read about methods and such I have been working on a program in order to get the user to type in a number and determine if it is prime or not. This is what I have so far.

```
print "Enter a number: "
num = gets.chomp

def prime(n)
  factors = []

  if num < 2
    puts "#{num} is a prime number"
  end

  while n % num == 0 and num < n
    factors.push(num)
    num += 1
  end

  return factors
end
```

Not even sure if I'm on the right track. Really lost. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you ran this code? What result you got?

Comment: 0 is not prime and < 2.

Comment: Ruby has inbuild library that can check number is prime or not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby - determine if a number is a prime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3594345/ruby-determine-if-a-number-is-a-prime)

Answer (score 2):

```
require 'prime'
print "Enter a number: "
num = gets.chomp

Prime.prime?(n)
```

Or, from the scratch:

```
def prime?(n)
  if n > 1
    min_condition = Math.sqrt(n).to_i  # The highest factor is necessary at most sqrt(n)
    factors = 0
    (1..min_condition).step(2).each do |i| # It's not necessary to check even numbers
      factors += 1 if (n.to_f / i) % 1 == 0
      break if factors > 1 # If the algorithm find 2 factors, the number isn't prime
    end
    !(factors > 1)
  else
    false
  end
end
```

Comment: How about `(1..min_condition).step(2).each`, then you can skip the `next if i.even?` bit. Also there's no need for the ternary at the end, `factors > 1` will already return a boolean.

Comment: Changes applied, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I know that you're doing this to learn Ruby, but keep in mind that you can just use [Prime.prime?](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.3/libdoc/prime/rdoc/Prime.html#method-i-prime-3F) to determine whether or not a number is prime.

```
require 'prime'

Prime.prime?(3)
#=> true 
Prime.prime?(4)
#=> false
```

As for your actual problem, you use both `num` and `n` inside your method, but `num` is defined outside, so won't be in scope. Also: you never seem to actually be calling `prime`.

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems with your program:

1. You want to `get the user to type in a number and determine if it is
   prime or not` but the output of your method `prime` doesn't answer
   this question. It will return an array.
2. If a number is less then 2, it is not a prime number ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number)), so this piece of your code is wrong:

> ```
> if num < 2
>   puts "#{num} is a prime number"
> end
> ```

3. There are plenty of ways to check if a number is a prime number or not, [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3594345/ruby-determine-if-a-number-is-a-prime) may help you to implement with Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use ruby base library than below code is useful for you

```
print "Enter a number: "
num = gets.chomp

def check_prime_number(num)
 num = num.to_i
 n = 1
 factors = []

 while (num >= n ) do
    if  (num % n == 0 )
        factors << n unless factors.include?(n)
    end
    n += 1
 end
 if ( factors.size > 2)
    puts "Factors of number #{num} :-> #{factors}" 
 elsif num > 0
    puts "#{num} is prime"
 end
end

check_prime_number(num)
```

Try if its helpful for you.